# Identify two continuous martingales in law as time-changed Brownian motions

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $W$ be a Brownian motion and $\alpha$ be a progressively measurable process taking values in $\mathbb R_+$. Set $\beta_t:=\max(\alpha_t, 1)$ for all $t\ge 0$. Define respectively $X$, $Y$ by

$$X_t:=\int_0^t \alpha_s \,dW_s,\quad Y_t:=\int_0^t \beta_s\, dW_s,\quad \forall t\ge 0.$$

It is known, e.g. by Dubins–Schwarz's theorem, that there exist some Brownian motion $B$ (with respect to some suitable filtration) and a non-negative stochastic process $h$ s.t.

$$\DeclareMathOperator\Law{Law}\Law(X)=\Law\bigl((B_{H_t})_{t\ge 0} \bigr),\quad\mbox{with}\quad  H_t:=\int_0^t h_s^2\,ds.$$

Define further $g_t:=\max(h_t, 1)$ for all $t\ge 0$. Can we prove

$$\quad\Law(Y)=\Law\bigl((B_{G_t})_{t\ge 0}\bigr), \quad\mbox{with}\quad  G_t:=\int_0^t g_s^2 \,ds?$$

Comment: To be clear the two Brownian motions will be different because Dubins-Schwarz is only a statement on distribution not almost surely i.e. $Law(X)=B_{H}$ and $Law(Y)=\tilde{B}_{G}$.

Comment: @ThomasKojar For two different Brownian motions the statement is clearly true. Here the desired identification is just in law, so I wish to known whether we may take the same Brownian motion

Comment: But that doesn't make sense really. The distribution statement is about probability measures i.e. comparing integrals over all omega. Whereas you are asking for having the same realization omega i.e. you are asking for almost sure statement. If it was true, then Dubin's Schwarz would be true almost surely.

Comment: @ThomasKojar I don's really see what you mean. For the deterministic case, my desired equality is clearly true

Comment: @ThomasKojar What I look for is just a equality in law

Comment: not it is not even true then.

Comment: But the equality in law is about integrals not about realizations. Whereas you are asking to have the same Brownian motion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145247/discussion-between-fawen90-and-thomas-kojar).

Comment: I may be mistaken, but do we not have $H_t = \langle X, X \rangle_t = \int_0^t \alpha_s^2 ds$, so $h_s = \alpha_s$? And thus $G_t = \int_0^t \beta_s^2 ds = \int_0^t \text{max} (\alpha_s, 1) ds = \int_0^t g_s^2 ds$?

Comment: @NateRiver We only have the identification in law between $X$ and $B_H$, where $B, H$ are defined in some abstract probability space (that may have nothing to do with $X$), so in generally we cannot claim $h=\alpha$